# I need to display image thumbnails in a plone 4 site most recent first. NOT oldest first which is default

Tags: plone

so it's a standard folder, add images, view by thumbnail, could do it manually by ordering them in contents, but that's getting back to flat html build by hand and I'm to old and tired for that. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to customize the thumbnail view, you can use old Plone collections (I fear that new ones can't sort items by folder position right now).

- enable old-style collection from types control panel
- create a collection item that search all images in the current folder
- put as sorting criteria the "position in parent" (you must enable it from the /atct_manageTopicIndex view, "all fields" section on the right)
- use reverse sorting
- use the collection as default view of the folder